# Unable to deploy VueJS with Gitlab Pages

Tags: vue.js, gitlab

I have used Gitlab pages in the past for React deployment and they work well except for VueJS. After following the example [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#gitlab-pages), I'm still unable to generate a website link for my Gitlab page even after GitLab CI pipeline was successful. Can anyone help with this?

This is what the .gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml file to be placed in the root of your repository

pages: # the job must be named pages
  image: node:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
    - mv public public-vue # GitLab Pages hooks on the public folder
    - mv dist public # rename the dist folder (result of npm run build)
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public # artifact path must be /public for GitLab Pages to pick it up
  only:
    - master
```

This is what the vue.config.js looks like:

```
// vue.config.js file to be place in the root of your repository
// make sure you update `yourProjectName` with the name of your GitLab project

module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/yourProjectName/'
    : '/'
}
```

After committing and pushing my changes, the GitLab CI pipeline was changed from running to successful. I was expecting to see my website link on `Settings > Pages`. I clicked on it, but I didn't see it. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you change `/yourProjectName/` to actual project name in `vue.config.js`?

Comment: Yes, I changed that.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#gitlab-pages-domain

Comment: Yes, I have read it carefully. Thank you. Currently, both the build and test have passed but there's no link on `Settings > Pages`

Comment: Did you enable "Gitlab Pages" for this project?

Comment: I believe I did, but I'm checking this again - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/

Comment: Yes, Gitlab Pages had been enabled. I am not getting any messages that it is disabled. Is there any particular command I can use to confirm that it is enabled? Also, this is the structure that I [have](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thnb84lzfe17dv4/Screenshot%202019-04-11%20at%2006.28.30.png?dl=0). Is it right?

Comment: any news on how to resolve this

Comment: I have exactly the same settings with .gitlab-ci.yml from here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#gitlab-pages and it works ok (it did not work with the vue.config.js from there, I had to set it explicitly to the value of my Project Name )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem of you assets links:
Because normaly in you local host you have all js files in a public folder, where you react or vuejs project join with you .html page with only a /assets/vuejs.files.js, so for deploy you need to rebase you url

This is a documentation for vite project deploy
**https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html**
where explain that you neet to rebase you url, example:
for you localhost:8000/ all files are in localhost:8000/assets/transpiled.vue.js but for deploy you url gona be diferent than `https://gitlab.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>` where you base URL is `'/<REPO>/'`.

Necessary to do it changes, if not you build project will request you assets file into / default base url, but not exist so, will redirect to gitlab and will redirect this again to login, so for this is you problem CORS.